# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 Internal keyboard "123..." produces unexpected characters

Tags: macos

Hi guys i hope you can help me out. My old MacBook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2012's number keys seems to have been connected to some other keys. My symptoms are that the expected key pressed is entered followed by another predictable but unexpected key press.

My keyboard is Danish QWERTY and i've had this issue before, started right after i installed Wow Classic and enabled the setting About ignoring system inputs. First time it seemed to be resolved after some time went but the this time i was unable to find a resolution for much longer.

[image]

Example:
1 enters F12/Volume up
2 enters <
3 enters $
My full 1234567890 enters 12<3$4¨5å6´789
(7 and 0 seems to be unaffected, 8 is Right arrow and 9 is Up arrow)

Having checked with external keyboards the issue is not present.
Changed language settings - issue persists
Checked wether any of Shift Fn CTRL ALT and CMD was enabled constantly with sticky keys and disabling them from "modifier keys" - persists
Tested with F1 and F2 as system and without - persists
SMC + NVRAM reset - Persists
Checked accesibilily settings - Nothing enabled under "Keyboard"
Checked "Mouse keys" - not enabled
Entered Accesibility Keyboard, pressing the 123... enters and highlight the correlating key when pressed on internal keyboard, pressing the key on the Keyboard interface doesn't.
Entered recovery with CMD+r and issue persists in terminal
Erased internal disk anyways to reinstall Catalina without a backup - persists.

I've been trying to locate some library folders, terminal commands (or even third party software to "block the input") to  but it seems like i have to live with it, any recommendations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If external keyboards work, I would suspect the internal one us damaged.

Comment: Yes you might be right, I simply have my doubts that this issue will persist since it started after the same settings were changed in the same game as the first time (which resolves itself).

Comment: Perhaps the support forum for the game can tell you if this is a common problem.  I unfortunately know nothing about what games can do to the keyboard mapping.

Comment: The issue has been resolved at least intermittently as I can currently type "12345..." without the additional key presses. No significant changes were made but I started playing Wow classic again after a erase and reinstall and now after two days of the games setting (disable os input) not being saved when I enable/disable the setting the issue seems to have gone away a lot like it started; after a couple days playing wow.